# apache - wsgi - python - basic example

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

So I was advised to use **wsgi** instead of cgi, so I tried to set it up with following settings for a **basic example**, without Django:

**specs:**

- linux Kubuntu, apache 2.4, python 3.5
- apache is running, mod_wsgi installed and enabled
- website files are in root/var/www/html/, I have sudo access to this folder
- the python 3.5 path is usr/bin/env python3
- the python script: "index.py, simplest of scripts, has been made executable
- the python executable lives in root/var/www/scripts

**Questions:**

- how do I make this function spit out it's result
- what's the deal with this wsgi script?  I have no need for that, I also do not want any wsgi extensions
- what apache directive do I need to introduce to run a script
- So where does the 'application' function live?

Really lost in this wsgi idea, some clarification might help

Comment: use `Flask`, `Bottle`, etc. Web Framework and build web page. They have built-in server so you don't need Apache at start.

Comment: Have you tried accessing index.py from a browser?  If so, what result do you get?

Comment: @furas: I deliberately do not want to use any web framework

Comment: @John Gordon: index.py works

Comment: if you don't want to use frameworks so you will only waste time for build elements which you have already in frameworks.

Comment: @furas:I like to know how the car works before I drive it :)

Comment: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so let's start with what I know and want, using the **minimalistic** approach:

most useful **info derived from** [shellhacks.com](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/modwsgi-Hello-World-Example) and [modwsgi.readthedocs.io](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/index.html)

- $ sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
- $ sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
- download latest mod-wsgi module package from [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases) and extract
- $ ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.5
- $ make
- $ sudo make install
- $ cd etc/apache2/mods-available/
- $ SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit wsgi.load

> LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

- $ sudo a2enmod wsgi
- $ sudo service apache2 restart
- place following 'spark.py' script in the document root folder of apache (which is root/var/www/html for me) using your favorite text editor (which in this case is Kate for me)

  ```
    $ kate /var/www/html/spark.py
  ```

> ```
> def application(environ, start_response):
>     status = '200 OK'
>     output = b'Hello World!\n'
>     response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
>                   ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
>     start_response(status, response_headers)
>     return [output]
> ```

- add the WSGI script alias directive to the etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

  ```
  $ sudo kate etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
  ```

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     #lots and lots of comments
>     some actual directives
>     like DocumentRoot /var/www/html
>
>     # more comments
>     more directives
>
>     # and all the way at the end
>     # THE ACTUAL DIRECTIVE
>     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/spark.py
>     <Directory /usr/lib/python3.7>
>         Require all granted
>     </Directory>
>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

- $ sudo service restart apache
- browse to localhost (if you are set up on the local apache server) and you should see most famous words in all programming history and man does it feel good to see those :)

Things to do: create app, point the script to that, ...

Comment: I had to run `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` as I was getting a Python.h file not found when running `make`.